# Filling in an allocation % column and have it display nicely

Tags: python, smartsheet-api

As part of my ongoing project of filling in project sheets programmatically with python, I am filling the % Allocated column (which is a column with the TAG 'GANTT_ALLOCATION'). I have been sending my values as floats, which works for the resource views, but displays as floats in smartsheet.
Using the curl sdk however seems to display as a percentage.
With Python:

```
this_allocation = 0.5
SS.models.Cell({
    'column_id': column_map['% Allocated'],
    'value': this_allocation,
    # 'display_value': "{:d}%".format(int(this_allocation*100))
})
```

Displays in Smartsheet: 0.5

with our own old python api that was using the rest api directly, it was getting displayed as 50%. Also if I type it directly in the UI it displays 50%.
I have tried setting a display value with no success.
I have also tried sending the value as an int (it caps at 1), as a string/unicode (it displays properly but doesn't calculate).

What am I missing?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to set the formatting of the cell/column as percentage. See the [API docs](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#formatting) for details on everything that's possible.

```
SS.models.Cell({
    'column_id': column_map['% Allocated'],
    'value': this_allocation,
    'format': ',,,,,,,,,,,,,,3,'
})
```